# Clebsch Gordan coefficients

Tags: special-functions, summation, physics

I'm trying to compute various sums which contain some CG coefficients, where the sum runs over the indexes m1,m2,m corresponding to each of the three angular momenta j1,j2,j. The thing is that when I try to evaluate such a sum, Mathematica shows some errors and then it throws the message "General::stop: Further output of ClebschGordan::phy will be suppressed during this calculation."

```
sum[j1_, j2_, j_] := Sum[ClebschGordan[{j1, m1}, {j2, m2}, {j, m}], {m1, -j1, j1, 
1}, {m2, -j2, j2, 1}, {m, -j, j, 1}];
N[sum[6, 2, 4]]
Do[Print[ClebschGordan[{6, m1}, {2, m2}, {4, m}]], {m1, -6, 6, 1}, {m2, -2, 2, 1}, {m, -4, 4, 1}]
```

I understand that for some values of {j1,m2},{j2,m2},{j,m} the CG coefficients are zero, but why does Mathematica throw error messages instead of just ignoring the term and keep going forward with the evaluation? Does the output error message mean that after a certain coefficient, Mathematica just simply stops evaluating terms, and my result will be incorrect?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: It is only a message , not an error.  See documentation of `ThreeJSymbol/ possible issues`

Comment: So just to make it clear, the message "General::stop: Further output of ClebschGordan::phy will be suppressed during this calculation." just means that Mathematica will stop showing error messages regarding the 3JS symbols ?

Comment: Yes, stop showing messages (no error!)

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @RobertPoenaru You can also suppress this very particular warning message with `Off[ClebschGordan::phy]` right from the start; this might even accelerate the evaluation since message handling is quite costly in _Mathematica_ since the FrontEnd has to be involved each time a message is thrown.

Comment: Yeah, it definitely helps!

Comment: Just to be clear about this: for particular combinations of the j's and m's in your table, the 3J symbols don't make sense. Luckily, *Mathematica* automatically sets the output to 0 for these particular cases, so you don't have to worry about suppressing the output (though sometimes it's useful to know that you are trying to evaluate something with an unphysical set of quantum numbers).

Comment: What is a "CB coefficient" and why oh why wouldn't your write that out in order to get more help?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork It literally says in the title what CB stands for my dude.

Comment: @march It makes perfect sense. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Ummm... forgive this physics PhD and former physics professor and physics textbook author..., but what does the "B" refer to in "Clebsch Gordon coefficients"?  ... my dude.

Comment: @RobertPoenaru:  Hah!  I didn't think so.

Comment: You are correct sir! My apologies, the abbreviation is now correct :)